# WooCommerce 2.1 endpoints - How to change content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

After updating to WooCommerce 2.1, I can see that custom pages have been replaced with endpoints. This makes it difficult to customise the "order-received" page.

The WooCommerce documentation only covers versions previous to 2.1 at present. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. I have the following questions:

1) How do I customise the order-received page? The url is displaying: http://www.mydomain.com/checkout/order-received/951/?key=wc_order_0000000000000. I have tried creating a new page (mydomain.com/checkout/order-recieved). This new page has been linked to the parent page "checkout", but it doesn't seem to work. The order received page I actually receive looks like a WooCommerce default.

2) Should I still set a loop redirect in PayPal once the payment is processed? If so, what url do I now provide?

Thank you!

Comment: I want to know this too. Also because Google Analytics tracking goes onto the order received page. I will wait with upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce got back to me today.

1) You can now edit the templates via plugins/woocommerce/templates.

2) You can read more about the setup for Paypal here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-standard

Good to know for those that need to customise the landing pages for each process. I DO NOT recommend editing these files directly as this will cause problems for future updates.

Comment: indeed, do not edit the templates files in the plugin folder. Instead copy them to your theme and Woo will use those files if they exist.

Comment: Yes DO NOT edit the templates in your plugin folder or the modifications you make will be lost when you update in the future. Move the folder inside your theme then edit!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise the order-received page, you can find it at thankyou.php file in templates/checkout/thankyou.php folders on woocommerce plugin directory, but if you want to redirect user to your custom page after clicking "place order" button, try add this to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function(){

global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order();
   if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; // or whatever url you want
   }
});
```